# How to find the total number of processes in Unix/Linux shell script

Tags: unix, grep, ps

I’m trying to find the total lines of running processes excepting the commands I’m using to create the listing.

Then to parse out the userID and the PID into a new list.

All within the same shell.

So far I have:

```
ps -ef | grep filename | wc -l
```

Comment: What’s the `grep filename` part for? It’s simply the output minus 4: `ps`, `grep`, `wc` and lastly, your `sh`/`bash` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is a command for processes list:

```
ps -ef | tr -s ' ' | awk '{ if ($8=="/usr/sbin/apache2") print $1, $2 }'
```

We print only first two columns of each line (userId, PID) where column8 is equal to **/usr/sbin/apache2** (process name)

and here is a command for processes count:

```
ps -ef | tr -s ' ' | awk '{ if ($8=="/usr/sbin/apache2") print $1, $2 }' | wc -l
```